# Changing properties of objects

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm making my own up and facing right now the problem: I found a guide on apple developer web site, but it's out of date and the code they show doesn't work nowadays, I would like to know how is it done right now

I've tried code of apple

```
//Example from their site. In my case the same but with UILabel
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:myNavBarBackgroundColor];
```

I expected to change globally text color, but could not

Comment: You posted an Objective C snippet but you tagged the question with Swift. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've tagged this question as Swift I suppose you're looking for Swift code. So, code which you've posted is in Objective-C so wherever you find this piece of code in Apple docs, on the top of the page you can find button for switching language to Swift

[image]

---

So, if you're looking for way, how to change barTintColor of `UINavigationBar` through the appearance, use this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = yourColor
```